# kivy passing widget to different class

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy. I really want to make the "yes" button inside the popup of the "popup_add" class to read the listview widget inside the "invoice" class.

I have searched many posts about passing widgets to different class, but all of them require having the class inside the parent class, i do not want to show the popup window unless the user clicked the button.

I have extract the important codes here:

python file:

```
class invoice(BoxLayout):
    shop_list_input = ObjectProperty()
    shop_name_input = ObjectProperty()

    def add_shop(self):
        add_popup = popup_add()
        add_popup.open()

class popup_add(Popup):

    def pop_yes(self, text_input,listView):
        store_name = text_input
        listView.adapter.data.extend([store_name])
        listView._trigger_reset_populate()
```

kivy file:

```
#: import main testKivy
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

invoice:

<invoice>:

    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    shop_name_input: shop_name
    shop_list_input: shop_list

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "60dp"

        TextInput:
# i found on google to use app to allow other class to access text, is there 
# a way to make listview global similar to app?
            on_text: app.input_sentence=self.text
            id: shop_name
            size_hint: 1,1

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"

        Button:
            text: "Add Store"
        size_hint_x: 15
        on_press: root.add_shop()

# anyway to make listview  widget accessible to other classes?
    ListView:
        id: shop_list
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=["Shop A","Shop B","Shop C"], cls=main.ShopListButton)

<popup_add>:
    title: 'notification'
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: .6,.3
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Yes"
# here is where i want to insert listview, inside root.pop_yes.
            on_press: root.pop_yes(app.input_sentence)
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, 'y':.25}
            size_hint: .2, .2
        Button:
            text: "No"
            on_press: root.dismiss()
            pos_hint: {"x": .6, 'y':.25}
            size_hint: .2, .2
        Label:
            text: "Are you sure to add " + app.input_sentence
            pos_hint: {"x": .2, 'y':.65}
            size_hint: .6, .3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ok so it is apparent that you are new to Kivy but no problem.

Ok so instead of making a separate class for the pop-up try creating a popup directly in your invoice class the python part of the program I will give you an example.

in my code, I did this

```
def success(self):
            popup18 = Popup(title='Loading Screen',content=Label(text='SENT',font_size=40,pos_hint={'center_y': 0.5, 'center_y': .5}),size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),auto_dismiss=True)
            popup18.open()
```

you can chk out the syntax for writing this stuff at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html

I try to minimize the number of classes but even so in my code I have more than 120 classes so up to you dude I hope I helped

P.S don't forget to import popup from Kivy

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `__init__` function for `popup_add` and have it accept a variable.

```
class invoice(BoxLayout):
    shop_list_input = ObjectProperty()
    shop_name_input = ObjectProperty()

    def add_shop(self):
        add_popup = popup_add(self.ids.shop_list)
        add_popup.open()

class popup_add(Popup):
    def __init__(self, shop_list_widget, **kwargs):
        super(popup_add, self).__init__(**kwargs):
        self.shop_list_widget = shop_list_widget

    def pop_yes(self, text_input,listView):
        store_name = text_input
        listView.adapter.data.extend([store_name])
        listView._trigger_reset_populate()
```

Doing it this way will still allow you to define the structure of the pop in the kv file.